# Get Cell Value After Text Search

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently working on Excel.
I have two columns (Column A and COlumn B). Column A contains a list of jobs(one job per cell), while column B contains the cost of each job per hour.

I'm trying to find a formula that tests if a given text or word (for example "Accountant") is contained in one of the cells in Column A, and then returns the corresponding value from Column B (next to it).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is =VLOOKUP("ACCOUNTANT";[RANGE COLUMN A AND B];2;FALSO)

Comment: THANKS BRO! IT WORKS!

Comment: Having a party with yourself?